# How do I pass (not f) as an f?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a filter function that takes in a predicate like odd? 
and processes a list. Here is the code

```
(define (manual-filter f? lst)
(cond
[(empty? lst) empty]
[(f? (first lst)) (cons (first lst) (manual-filter f? (rest lst)))]
[else (manual-filter f? (rest lst))]))
```

How do I go about passing (not (f?)) as the function?

Comment: `(define even? (compose not odd?))`?

Comment: it's for a homework question so we can't use abstract functions such as compose, and odd? was an example, it could be any predicate

Answer (score 4):

the `not` function has the signature `Any -> Boolean`. And is essentially:

```
(define (not x)
  (if (eq? x #f) #t #f))
```

What you are looking for is a function that inverts the output to another given function. (Or basically, a function of the signature: `(Any -> Boolean) -> (Any -> Boolean)`

As @Sylwester suggested, the easiest way to do this is with `compose`. You could define it as:

```
(define (invert f)
  (compose not f))
```

Now you could, say, define `even?` as:

```
(define even? (invert odd?))
```

You can also define `invert` without using `compose`. I'll give you the template and leave the rest as an exercise:

```
;; Invert the results of a predicate
;; (Any -> Boolean) -> (Any -> Boolean)
(define (invert f)
  (lambda (x)
    (cond
      [(f x) ...]
      [else ...])))
```

(Note that racket has a shorthand for functions like this:

```
 (define ((invert f) x)
   (cond
     [(f x) ...]
     [else ...]))
```

Comment: It is not `invert`. It is [`negate`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=negate#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._negate%29%29).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Write a function, which returns a lambda-expression with applies `not` to the application of your predicate function on any argument.

```
(define (my-not predicate-func)
  (lambda (x) (not (predicate-func x))))
```

`(my-not f?)` returns then a function which is the inverted predicate function of `f?`.
(So no `compose` needed ... - well `my-not` is manually `compose`-ing the function `not` with `f?` (the predicate-function) in its function definition body).

I called it `my-not` to not to overwrite the already existing `not` function in Racket which converts booleans thus returns a boolean.
(`my-not` takes a function and returns a function - `Function -> Function` or `lambda -> lambda` :) .)

`my-not` could be also called `invert`.

**Application**

Thus, you can give `(my-not f?)` to your `manual-filter` function instead of `f?`:

```
(manual-filter (my-not f?) lst)
```

**Try out**

You can also test:

```
(even? 3) ;; #f
(even? 4) ;; #t

((my-not even?) 3) ;; #t
((my-not even?) 4) ;; #f

;; so `(my-not even?)` behaves exactly like `odd?` - the inverse of `even?`
(odd? 3) ;; #t
(odd? 4) ;; #f
```